# what is SearchPathDomainMask and SearchPathDirectory in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, file, directory, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to understand iOS and macOS file system

but SearchPathDomainMask and SearchPathDirectory are very confusing me

```
let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
```

in this code, I think this URL is documented directory path in the user domain

if there is document directory in local domain is this code possible?

```
let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .localDomainMask)
```

is SearchPathDirectory just enum for well-known file URL?

what is the purpose of domain mask or domain